# how to improve the code (Delphi) for loading and searching in a dictionary?

Tags: delphi, hash

I'm a Delphi programmer.
I have made a program who uses dictionaries with words and expressions (loaded in program as "array of string").
It uses a search algorithm based on their "checksum" (I hope this is the correct word).
A string is transformed in integer based on this:

```
var
   FHashSize: Integer; //stores the value of GetHashSize
   HashTable, HashTableNoCase: array[Byte] of Longword;
   HashTableInit: Boolean = False;

const
   AnsiLowCaseLookup: array[AnsiChar] of AnsiChar = (
      #$00, #$01, #$02, #$03, #$04, #$05, #$06, #$07,
      #$08, #$09, #$0A, #$0B, #$0C, #$0D, #$0E, #$0F,
      #$10, #$11, #$12, #$13, #$14, #$15, #$16, #$17,
      #$18, #$19, #$1A, #$1B, #$1C, #$1D, #$1E, #$1F,
      #$20, #$21, #$22, #$23, #$24, #$25, #$26, #$27,
      #$28, #$29, #$2A, #$2B, #$2C, #$2D, #$2E, #$2F,
      #$30, #$31, #$32, #$33, #$34, #$35, #$36, #$37,
      #$38, #$39, #$3A, #$3B, #$3C, #$3D, #$3E, #$3F,
      #$40, #$61, #$62, #$63, #$64, #$65, #$66, #$67,
      #$68, #$69, #$6A, #$6B, #$6C, #$6D, #$6E, #$6F,
      #$70, #$71, #$72, #$73, #$74, #$75, #$76, #$77,
      #$78, #$79, #$7A, #$5B, #$5C, #$5D, #$5E, #$5F,
      #$60, #$61, #$62, #$63, #$64, #$65, #$66, #$67,
      #$68, #$69, #$6A, #$6B, #$6C, #$6D, #$6E, #$6F,
      #$70, #$71, #$72, #$73, #$74, #$75, #$76, #$77,
      #$78, #$79, #$7A, #$7B, #$7C, #$7D, #$7E, #$7F,
      #$80, #$81, #$82, #$83, #$84, #$85, #$86, #$87,
      #$88, #$89, #$8A, #$8B, #$8C, #$8D, #$8E, #$8F,
      #$90, #$91, #$92, #$93, #$94, #$95, #$96, #$97,
      #$98, #$99, #$9A, #$9B, #$9C, #$9D, #$9E, #$9F,
      #$A0, #$A1, #$A2, #$A3, #$A4, #$A5, #$A6, #$A7,
      #$A8, #$A9, #$AA, #$AB, #$AC, #$AD, #$AE, #$AF,
      #$B0, #$B1, #$B2, #$B3, #$B4, #$B5, #$B6, #$B7,
      #$B8, #$B9, #$BA, #$BB, #$BC, #$BD, #$BE, #$BF,
      #$C0, #$C1, #$C2, #$C3, #$C4, #$C5, #$C6, #$C7,
      #$C8, #$C9, #$CA, #$CB, #$CC, #$CD, #$CE, #$CF,
      #$D0, #$D1, #$D2, #$D3, #$D4, #$D5, #$D6, #$D7,
      #$D8, #$D9, #$DA, #$DB, #$DC, #$DD, #$DE, #$DF,
      #$E0, #$E1, #$E2, #$E3, #$E4, #$E5, #$E6, #$E7,
      #$E8, #$E9, #$EA, #$EB, #$EC, #$ED, #$EE, #$EF,
      #$F0, #$F1, #$F2, #$F3, #$F4, #$F5, #$F6, #$F7,
      #$F8, #$F9, #$FA, #$FB, #$FC, #$FD, #$FE, #$FF);

implementation

function GetHashSize(const Count: Integer): Integer;
begin
   if Count < 65 then
      Result := 256
   else
      Result := Round(IntPower(16, Ceil(Log10(Count div 4) / Log10(16))));
end;

function Hash(const Hash: LongWord; const Buf; const BufSize: Integer): LongWord;
var P: PByte;
   I: Integer;
begin
   P := @Buf;
   Result := Hash;
   for I := 1 to BufSize do
   begin
      Result := HashTable[Byte(Result) xor P^] xor (Result shr 8);
      Inc(P);
   end;
end;

function HashStrBuf(const StrBuf: Pointer; const StrLength: Integer; const Slots: LongWord): LongWord;
var P: PChar;
   I, J: Integer;
begin
   if not HashTableInit then
      InitHashTable;
   P := StrBuf;
   if StrLength <= 48 then // Hash all characters for short strings
      Result := Hash($FFFFFFFF, P^, StrLength)
   else
   begin
      // Hash first 16 bytes
      Result := Hash($FFFFFFFF, P^, 16);
      // Hash last 16 bytes
      Inc(P, StrLength - 16);
      Result := Hash(Result, P^, 16);
      // Hash 16 bytes sampled from rest of string
      I := (StrLength - 48) div 16;
      P := StrBuf;
      Inc(P, 16);
      for J := 1 to 16 do
      begin
         Result := HashTable[Byte(Result) xor Byte(P^)] xor (Result shr 8);
         Inc(P, I + 1);
      end;
   end;
  // Mod into slots
   if Slots <> 0 then
      Result := Result mod Slots;
end;

procedure InitHashTable;
var I, J: Byte;
   R: LongWord;
begin
   for I := $00 to $FF do
   begin
      R := I;
      for J := 8 downto 1 do
         if R and 1 <> 0 then
            R := (R shr 1) xor $EDB88320
         else
            R := R shr 1;
      HashTable[I] := R;
   end;
   Move(HashTable, HashTableNoCase, Sizeof(HashTable));
   for I := Ord('A') to Ord('Z') do
      HashTableNoCase[I] := HashTableNoCase[I or 32];
   HashTableInit := True;
end;
```

The result of the HashStrBuf is "and (FHashSize - 1)" and is used as index in an "array of array of Integer" (of FHashSize size) to store the index of the string from that "array of string".
This way, when searches for a string, it's transformed in "checksum" and then the code searches in the "branch" with this index comparing this string with the strings from dictionary who have the same "checksum".

Ideally each string from dictionary should have unique checksum. But in the "real world" about 2/3 share the same "checksum" with other words. Because of that the search is not that fast.
In these dictionaries strings are composed of this characters: ['a'..'z',#224..#246,#248..#254,#154,#156..#159,#179,#186,#191,#190,#185,'0'..'9', '''']
Is there any way to improve the "hashing" so the strings would have more unique "checksums"?
Oh, one way is to increase the size of that "array of array of Integer"  (FHashSize) but it cannot be increased too much because it takes a lot of Ram.

Another thing: these dictionaries are stored on HDD only as words/expressions (not the "checksums"). Their "checksum" is generated at program startup. But it takes a lot of seconds to do that...
Is there any way to speed up the startup of the program? Maybe by improving the "hashing" function, maybe by storing the "checksums" on HDD and loading them from there...

Any input would be appreciated...

PS: here is the code to search:

```
function TDictionary.LocateKey(const Key: AnsiString): Integer;
var i, j, l, H: Integer;
   P, Q: PChar;
begin
   Result := -1;
   l := Length(Key);
   H := HashStrBuf(@Key[1], l, 0) and (FHashSize - 1);
   P := @Key[1];
   for i := 0 to High(FHash[H]) do  //FHash is that "array of array of integer"
   begin
      if l <> FKeys.ItemSize[FHash[H][i]] then //FKeys.ItemSize is an byte array with the lengths of strings from dictionary
         Continue;
      Q := FKeys.Pointer(FHash[H][i]); //pointer to string in dictionary
      for j := 0 to l - 1 do
         if (P + j)^ <> (Q + j)^ then
            Break;
      if j = l then
      begin
         Result := FHash[H][i];
         Exit;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: `array of string` sounds dubious. Please tell me you don't load the file with a line like: `SetLength(strings, Length(strings)+1)`.

Comment: @David Heffernan Delphi 7. Of course not, it's one of the worst codes... I know the the length of the dictionary before I load it from file so I set the length of the array once and load the elements.

Comment: How big is the disk file that you read? How many strings? Is the startup time spent reading the disk or computing the hashes? Surely it's the former. Are you buffering the reads?

Comment: The loading code it's a lot more complicated but suffice to say that is loading the hole file in array very fast (HDD max read speed, I don't think it can be improved) then it spends over 90% of the total time hashing (here I want to improve). How many strings: a few dozens dictionaries with sizes between 100 and millions of strings.

Comment: Oh, total size of the dictionaries is about 200 MB.

Comment: Not the best for large amount of strings. Unfortunately, Delphi doesn't have anything better (maybe till the hash based generic containers in D2009+ which I haven't studied fully). T(String)list are array wrappers too

Comment: Ok. I tried some time ago to switch to D2009 but unfortunately in any D200x the memory taken by my program is increasing with 60..70%. And since my program takes now about 300 MB I think I'll stay at Delphi 7...

Comment: @Cosmin If you want the memory use to be maintained low, just use AnsiString instead of string in the storage part of your code. About memory usage, consider using external mapped files, since I guess the dictionaries content won't change much. Take a look at our SynBigTable.

Comment: @A Bouchez First, I used Ansistring when I tested. Second, the problem is not from the string/ansistring array. I checked and is from FHash (that array of array of integer); I checked this thoroughly. In my program I don't actually use "array of string/ansistring" in FKeys but a custom array with low Ram impact in any Delphi version. And, by the way, FKeys are not the cause of the bottleneck (if there is one).

Comment: A related question, with very interesting TRIE implementation.  This solution by Cosmin Prund is very nice:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297057/efficient-data-structure-for-guids

Answer (score 4):

Don't [reinvent the wheel](http://www.latiumsoftware.com/en/articles/00011.php)!

IMHO your hashing is far from efficient, and your collision algorithm can be improved.

Take a look for instance at the IniFiles unit, and the THashedStringList.
It's a bit old, but a good start for a string list using hashes.

There are a lot of good Delphi implementation of such, like in [SuperObject](http://superobject.googlecode.com) and a lot of [other code](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Algorithms/index.html)...

Take a look at our [SynBigTable](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/BigTable) unit, which can handle arrays of data in memory or in file very fast, with full indexed searches. Or [our latest TDynArray wrapper](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI) around any dynamic array of data, to implement TList-like methods to it, including fast binary search. I'm quite sure it could be faster than your hand-tuned code using hashing, if you use an ordered index then fast binary search.

**Post-Scriptum:**

About pure hashing speed of a string content, take a look at this function - rename RawByteString into AnsiString, PPtrInt into PPointer, and PtrInt into Integer for Delphi 7:

```
function Hash32(const Text: RawByteString): cardinal;
function SubHash(P: PCardinalArray): cardinal;
{$ifdef HASINLINE}inline;{$endif}
var s1,s2: cardinal;
    i, L: PtrInt;
const Mask: array[0..3] of cardinal = (0,$ff,$ffff,$ffffff);
begin
  if P<>nil then begin
    L := PPtrInt(PtrInt(P)-4)^; // fast lenght(Text)
    s1 := 0;
    s2 := 0;
    for i := 1 to L shr 4 do begin // 16 bytes (4 DWORD) by loop - aligned read
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[1]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[2]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[3]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),16);
    end;
    for i := 1 to (L shr 2)and 3 do begin // 4 bytes (DWORD) by loop
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),4);
    end;
    inc(s1,P^[0] and Mask[L and 3]);      // remaining 0..3 bytes
    inc(s2,s1);
    result := s1 xor (s2 shl 16);
  end else
    result := 0;
end;
begin // use a sub function for better code generation under Delphi
  result := SubHash(pointer(Text));
end;
```

There is even a pure asm version, even faster, in our [SynCommons.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas) unit. I don't know any faster hashing function around (it's faster than crc32/adler32/IniFiles.hash...). It's based on adler32, but use DWORD aligned reading and summing for even better speed. This could be improved with SSE asm, of course, but here is a fast pure Delphi hash function.

Then don't forget to use "multiplication"/"binary and operation" for hash resolution, just like in IniFiles. It will reduce the number of iteration to your list of hashs.

But since you didn't provide the search source code, we are not able to know what could be improved here.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent, I didn't write the code now but years ago, now I'm just trying to improve it. Thank you for the suggestions, I'll look into them...

Comment: @Cosmin  It was not clear to me that your problem was about hashing speed. So I just edited my answer in order to give you the faster Hash function I wrote for strings under Delphi 7.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I added the search code to my question. There are 2 more unrecognized by the compiler: PCardinalArray and PtrUInt.

Comment: Since in the question I asked also about a way to decrease the number of strings with the same checksum I compared the 2 codes. Unfortunately with your code that number has increased by 55%...

Comment: Sorry, but Hash32 is much faster than HashStrBuf. If you use a loop with only the function calls, you'll see it's faster. On my Pentium 4, Hash32 is twice faster than your HashStrBuf function: for 1000000 iterations over a 500 chars string, Hash32 needs 86 ms, whereas HashStrBuf takes 167 ms. So the bottleneck is NOT in the hash function by in your code general implementation. You were wrong about your guess. Did you use a Profiler to find the real bottleneck of your application? You should have started with that before guessing that the hash function was faulty.

Comment: About collision, you should take a look at the crc32 function: I guess you will have less collisions. Adler32/Hash32 is not perfect from this point of view. You'll find a pure asm fast implementation of crc32 (faster than the one in zlib.pas) in our SynZip unit.

Comment: I don't think I'm that wrong (worst case scenario). I tested on normal computers and with real dictionary of 1.3 millions words not with a 500 one cycled 1000000 times. There is a difference... And by the way, if you still think that the bottleneck is in my code, at least be helpful and so help me to find the problem not say all the time that my code is faulty. I didn't say that your code is faulty but you're very quick to think that from "0.5%". That tells me a lot about you... Do what you want but if you don't wanna help please stay away from my questions.

Comment: @Cosmin Sorry for being a bit rude - this is because I'm no native, so my English is a bit too "technical"... I go straight to the point. There is no fault here. I was only telling that if a hashing function which is 100% faster only speeds your average execution time by 0.5%... then 99% of the time is spent outside the hashing function. You would better go and check where 99% of the time is spent. That's why using a profiler always makes sense. First human guess about speed optimization is commonly wrong guess. For you and for me. That's why I wrote a benchmark to see if Hash32 was faster.

Comment: @Cosmin did you try crc32 hashing function?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Delphi 7, consider using Julian Bucknall's lovely Delphi data types code,  EzDsl (Easy Data Structures Library).

Now you don't have to reinvent the wheel as another wise person has also said.

You can download ezdsl, a version that I have made work with both Delphi 7, and recent unicode delphi versions, [here](http://cid-f5bb35ae00415bc7.office.live.com/embedicon.aspx/Public/ezdsl.zip).

In particular the unit name EHash contains a hash table implementation, which has various hashing algorithms plug-inable, or you can write your own plugin function that just  does the hashing function of your choice.

As a word to the wise, if you are using a Unicode Delphi version; I would be careful about hashing your unicode strings with a code library like this, without checking how its hashing algorithms perform on your system.  The OP here is using Delphi 7, so Unicode is not a factor for the original question.

Comment: P Ok. I tested this code. Unfortunately the hashing is 12% slower and the rate of "collision" is 58% higher. Thanks anyway.

Comment: +1 Julian's code is great. His book about Algorithms is a MUST HAVE for every Delphi programmer. Even if it could look old, it's still the number one in my Delphi book list. Available at lulu and worth its price! See http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/the-tomes-of-delphi-algorithms-and-data-structures/488272

Comment: @Cosmin, I assume you tried EHash? Which Hash function did you try ? ELF? PJW? BKDR?  Which one is 12% slower and has a 58% higher collision rate, and for what data set did it have such a property? If you didn't try something else, it uses HashBKDR, which is derived from a famous K&R technique.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find a database (without checksums) a lot quicker.  Maybe try sqlite which will give you a single file database.  There are many Delphi Libraries available.

Comment: I never found a case where DB loading was faster than manual loading. Unless the manual code was _really_ broken.

Comment: +1 to @Marco, databases are faster to develop, but never faster to run!

Comment: There will be faster in-memory-database technologies, than this homebrew in-memory database that this guy is working on.  And more reliable.  Remember, that database is a vague term these days.  There are a lot of very fast in-memory nosql-dbs that can load and parse their data sets very quickly.