# A trie implementation in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, data-structures, trie

Anyone knows a ready-to-use trie [sic] implementation in Delphi? An optimized trie would be even better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean tree instead of trie? Parent and Child relations? Any specific about the tree? What would you like to be optimized? You mean you want to be balanced?

Comment: @LarsTruijens: I suspect the OP really does mean a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Trie or prefix tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: See COSMIN's Answer here;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297057/efficient-data-structure-for-guids

Comment: @LarsTruijens, I really meant "trie". Basic Trie implementations take much more memory than hashtables, but there are scopes of optimization to solve this issue. Here's a JavaScript example: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far this seems to be the only choice. Good thing is it is generic.

**[Compact Generic Trie Dictionary](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=233776)**

Answer (score 1):

Try [this one](http://www.softcomplete.com/hashtrie.asp) from softcomplete. Download link is at the bottom.

Haven't got any experience with it, just found it on Google when searching for `Delphi "Trie"`. The quotes were needed, or else Google is so smart to change it to 'try', which is probably why you didn't find it yourself in the first place. Free tip. :)